# peace lily not flowering properly

Tags: flowers

Why are my peace lily flowers only growing halfway up?  The leaves are beautiful and they are strong.  The flowers continue to grow except you can't see them because they are inside the leaves.  They don't grow all the way up

Comment: A photo would be helpful - are the flowers actually opening up fully before they've got taller?

Comment: The flower is opening up by not getting taller..    Growing only halfway up